# How to make Blockchain Assets Indelible?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, smartcontracts

Is there a certain way to commit a transaction using the Hyperledger Composer API once I insert or update an asset in a registry?

The reason why I ask this question is, after I insert an asset, I can delete it from the registry using the Registry.Remove() API call. Given that data in the BlockChain should be indelible, how do I achieve this?

Of course, I can put ACL's to prevent a certain participant from accessing the delete transaction, but that is not making it truly indelible. What if the owner of the data wants to delete his/her action?!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a Remove method on a Registry, you are removing the object (Asset or Participant) from the **State Database**.  At the same time you are also writing a RemoveParticipant transaction to the **Ledger**.  All transactions can then be queried / viewed.

So the object is indelibly on the Ledger, as is the record of its removal - but it does not appear in the current state.

You can check this yourself by working through the online Playground Tutorial, then create and delete a Participant (or Asset), then finally look at "All Transactions".